# Binary to decimal conversion by grouping

Tags: binary

It is possible to convert a binary number to a hexadecimal number by grouping digits in groups of 4 and getting a hexadecimal digit out of each group.
Can the same be done in a binary to decimal conversion?

Say I have 1110010110 and I want to convert it to decimal

Can the "grouping" method be applied here?

Yes, I know how to convert that number to decimal by simply multypling each digit by a power 2 of and then adding them together, but that's not what I am asking for. I am asking for the "grouping" method

Comment: 10 is not a perfect power of 2. Problem solved.

Comment: That was quick, yeah. Thank you!